# How to have adb recognizing my Nikon s800c on windows 7?

Tags: adb, nikon-s800c

Has anyone got ADB to work correctly for the Nikon S800C?

I've followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-discuss/ky_YMMxPxQ4), but to no avail.

I am using Windows 7, and can see a yellow alert mark in the device manager.

Comment: What steps have you tried specifically? Can you link? Have you installed the ADB drivers?

Comment: @LiamW I've followed the previous question at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831875/nikon-s800c-adb-on-windows-7), that had the mentioned link. (edited to add it).

Comment: Try installing PDA.net, it has a lot of Android device drivers bundled together. You can uninstall the software afterwards. http://junefabrics.com/android/